# javascript buttons to show/hide areas of the page doesn't stay toggled

Tags: javascript, styles, display

This code is briefly showing the area that the button click sets display:block, But then the area immediately disappears. for whatever reason the toggle of the area does not stick.  Please advise:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHide(input) {
        if (input == "look"){
            document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("2").style = "display:block";
        }
        return;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <form >
        <fieldset>
            <button onclick="ShowHide('1')">Area 1</button>
            <button onclick="ShowHide('2')">Area 2</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="1" style="display:none">
    Area 1
</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none">
    area 2
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by using `if (input == "look")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **event object** and d**ata attributtes**:

```js
function ShowHide(input) {
   // If you don't want the form to refresh the page, use preventDefault
   event.preventDefault(); 
   // Using dataset you can access the data attributes from the button that fired the event
   document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.divid).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <form >
        <fieldset>
            <button onclick="ShowHide()" data-divid="1">Area 1</button> <!- Add data attributes to your buttons ->
            <button onclick="ShowHide()" data-divid="2">Area 2</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="1" style="display:none">
    Area 1
</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none">
    area 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the refresh of the page on form submission you will need to use `event.preventDefault();`

I believe something along the lines of the following is what you are trying to achieve:

```
<div id="main">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <button onclick="showHide('myDiv1')">Area 1</button>
                    <button onclick="showHide('myDiv2')">Area 2</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="myDiv1" style="display:none">
            Area 1
        </div>
        <div id="myDiv2" style="display:none">
            Area 2
        </div>



<script>
            function showHide(elemId) {
                 event.preventDefault();
        var x = document.getElementById(elemId);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nk8v7xp60) is the code on [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nk8v7xp60).